# Binding not working for collections in knockoutjs

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am trying to use knockout.js to show a specification object on the UI. The specification has a name and it has a few parameterInfo rows. Each ParameterInfo row has a ParameterPartNumber and a bunch of SignalInputs. Each SignalInput has just one property called Name. I am able to show the specification name, the parameterInfo rows and ParameterPartNumber but am not able to show the bunch of SignalInput Names that I have even though the SpecificationModel has the values. I am using the following code:

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="specificationHeader">

    Name : <input data-bind='value: Name' />
    <br />
    <br />

</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Parameter Part
            </th>

            <th>
                Signal Inputs
            </th>            
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ParameterInfos">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input data-bind='value: ParameterPartNumber' />
            </td>

            <td>
                <ul data-bind="foreach: SignalInputs">                    
                    <li><span data-bind='text: Name' /></li>
                </ul>
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript/Knockout code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var SpecificationModel = function (specification) {

        var self = this;

        self.Name = ko.observable(specification.Name);

        self.ParameterInfos =   ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(specification.ParameterInfos, function (ParameterInfo) {
            return { ParameterPartNumber: ParameterInfo.ParameterPartNumber, SignalInputs: ko.observableArray(ParameterInfo.SignalInputs) };
        }));

    };

    var specificationData = '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SpecificationData)';
    var viewModel = new SpecificationModel($.parseJSON(specificationData))
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

When I run the program in debug mode, I can see the following values:

```
var specificationData = '{"Name":"Specification One",
                          "ParameterInfos": [{"ParameterPartNumber":"26-20700-002", "SignalInputs":[{"Name":"Park Brake"},{"Name":"Neutral"}]} ]}';
```

It's strange because I was able to get an almost similar example working thanks to the answers for the following question:

[Need to pass initial viewmodel data from ASP.NET MVC to knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657002/need-to-pass-initial-viewmodel-data-from-asp-net-mvc-to-knockout-js/9658321#9658321)

Still, somehow the binding code is not working. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Ok, the following lines work:

```
<td data-bind="foreach: SignalInputs">
    <ul >                    
        <li><span data-bind='text: Name' /></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

But, the following lines don't

```
<td>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: SignalInputs">                    
        <li><span data-bind='text: Name' /></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

Any idea why? The latter site of lines work in the other stackoverflow example question I cited.

Comment: Maybe you can reproduce off of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qXCLu/

Comment: Thanks @RP Niemeyer. I checked the fiddle and it seems to have the same problem that I am having. It doesn't show the SignalInputs. Actually, it doesn't show any data.

Comment: What browser are you using?  It shows Park Brake and Neutral in Chrome/IE9/Firefox.  What do you see on the fiddle?

Comment: I tried it on Chrome, IE 9 and IE 8. Doesn't work on any one of these.

Comment: Can you check the dev console for errors or look at the network tab? Otherwise, click on "Manage Resources" and try to navigate to the link to the KO file.  It seems like maybe you are not being served the file properly from your location.  It looks fine to me in all browsers.

Comment: The line in my code which has <input data-bind='value: ParameterPartNumber' /> is working properly. I can see the proper ParameterPartNumber value. So, I don't think that the KO file has a problem. It's only the collections that are having an issue. Also, if I put an alert in function(ParameterInfo), it shows the proper values. It's just not binding properly in the html.

Comment: Hey @RP Niemeyer. I found out that things start working if we put the data-bind code inside the <td> instead of the <ul>. I have included the working code in my question at the end. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I see.  You have an issue with your `span`.  It needs to be `<span></span>` instead of `<span />`

Answer (score 4):

In my experience when you run into weird binding errors, it often stems from the `for-each` binding. Because I've had so many issues with it, I pretty much just go the "containerless" route:

```
<!-- ko foreach: myItems -->
    <li>Item <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I modified my code like this:    <td>
                    <ul>
                        <!-- ko foreach: SignalInputNames -->
                        <li><span data-bind='text: Name' /></li>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </ul>
                </td> and now i do get the unordered list but I get the last element twice. Any idea why?

Comment: Update your answer so we can see the formatting. It's impossible to read in comments.

Comment: Nice tip and saved me. foreach on dom elements is totally buggy. $data doesn't seem to bind correctly. Use this method everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems binding, but my issue turned out to be because I was using an early version of (knockout 1.2.1) that didn't support the foreach binding.  It didn't throw an error for an unrecognised binding function though, just when I tried to reference an element within the collection I was supposedly binding to making it hard to debug.

In the end I used a template binding as per the answer here: [Stackoverflow: knockout javascript foreach binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099657/knockout-javascript-foreach-binding)

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading in the KnockoutJS documentation that the bindings run into issues with empty elements like `<span .... />` and they suggest using `<span ...></span>` or even `<span ...>&nbsp;</span>` ([the latter being a countermeasure to an IE6 bug](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html#note_4_about_an_ie_6_whitespace_quirk)).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is relevant since this answer was posted so long ago but I was having an issue with foreach as well. I noticed that the error was coming from a jquery call in knockout (i was using knockout-2.0.0) and jquery-2.1.1.  When I updated to knockout-3.1.0, this problem was solved.

2.0.0 was installed when I installed knockout.mapping via nuget and it probably depends on 2.0.0 at least. Hope this helps someone...