# knockout javascript foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to allow a user to create a casting and add an array of categories to this casting object.  I was trying to use knockout's foreach binding to the array of categories and let users add new categories to the casting.  I have created a jsfiddle to illustrate what I'm trying to explain here.
http://jsfiddle.net/msell/ueNg7/16/

The JSON object gets built up correctly as a user modifies a casting, but I cant quite get the list of castings to display.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have several problems:

### You are using Knockout 1.2.1

The `foreach` binding was not added until Knockout 2.0.

### You are not using an `observableArray`

You need to modify your `categories` property to be a `ko.observableArray()`, instead of just an empty array. Otherwise Knockout will not be able to observe when you `push` to it, and the `remove` method will not exist.

### Your `this` binding is wrong.

When called from event handlers, `this` will be set incorrectly. You can fix this in various ways, [discussed in length in the Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html), but one easy fix is to change the references to `viewModel` instead of to `this`.

---

To fix all these, you should upgrade to Knockout 2.0, and change your view model declaration to be

```
var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable(''),
    description: ko.observable(''),
    categories: ko.observableArray(),
    categoryToAdd: ko.observable(''),

    removeCategory: function(category) {
        viewModel.categories.remove(category);
    },

    addCategory: function() {
        viewModel.categories.push(new Category(viewModel.categoryToAdd()));
        viewModel.categoryToAdd('');
    }
};
```

Here is a corrected JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ueNg7/19/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ko.observableArray for you array otherwise Knockout wont know when you change your array and wont update, also you should use a template instead, read here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_2_using_the_foreach_option_with_a_named_template

```
var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable(''),
    description: ko.observable(''),
    categories: ko.observableArray([]),
    categoryToAdd: ko.observable(''),
    removeCategory: function(category) {
        this.categories.remove(category);
    },

    addCategory: function() {

        this.categories.push(new Category(this.categoryToAdd()));
        this.categoryToAdd('');
    }
};
```